# unable to load csv file into snowflake with the COPY INTO command

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

> End of record reached while expected to parse column '"VEGETABLE_DETAILS_PLANT_HEIGHT"["HIGH_END_OF_RANGE":5]'
>
> File 'veg_plant_height.csv', line 8, character 14
> Row 3, column "VEGETABLE_DETAILS_PLANT_HEIGHT"["HIGH_END_OF_RANGE":5]
> If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.

this is my table

```
create or replace table VEGETABLE_DETAILS_PLANT_HEIGHT ( 
   PLANT_NAME text(7), 
   VEG_HEIGHT_CODE text(1), 
   UNIT_OF_MEASURE text(2),
   LOW_END_OF_RANGE number(2),
   HIGH_END_OF_RANGE number(2)
   );
```

and the COPY INTO command I used

```
copy into vegetable_details_plant_height
from @like_a_window_into_an_s3_bucket
files = ( 'veg_plant_height.csv')
file_format = ( format_name=VEG_CHALLENGE_CC );
```

and the csv file `https://uni-lab-files.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/veg_plant_height.csv`

Comment: Please include the code used to create the file format and some sample dataset

Comment: The file format was created manually it is of type csv

Comment: I get that it was created beforehand, but without looking at your sample data and make up of the file format, it's not possible to help you. It's not that difficult to figure out how the file format was created. Just do `select get_ddl('file_format', 'VEG_CHALLENGE_CC')`;

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT VEG_CHALLENGE_CC
 SKIP_HEADER = 1
; I got this after using the statement

Comment: You can use the VALIDATE function to identify the reason why your COPY from the file failed. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-internal-tutorial-resolve.html

Answer (score 1):

The error "`End of record reached while expected to parse column`" means Snowflake detected there were less than expected columns when processing the current row.

Please review your CSV file and make sure each row has correct number of columns. The error said on line 8.

Answer (score 1):

The table has 5 columns but source file consist values for four columns due to this copy command returns the error. In order to resolve the issue you can modified the copy command as mentioned below:

```
copy into vegetable_details_plant_height(PLANT_NAME, UNIT_OF_MEASURE, LOW_END_OF_RANGE, HIGH_END_OF_RANGE)
from (select $1, $2, $3, $4 from @like_a_window_into_an_s3_bucket)
files = ( 'veg_plant_height.csv') file_format = ( format_name=VEG_CHALLENGE_CC );
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in csv file data in one column is in "" and the names are separated by , so u need to use that FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"' type option