# Getting error while loading data into table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting this error while loading data into snowflake table from tsv format.

### Unable to copy files into table.
End of record reached while expected to parse column "SALESFORCE_ACTIVITIES_REPORT" ["INSERT_DATE".19]' File '@SALESFORCE_ACTIVITIES_REPORT/ui1659508402073/Salesforce Report- Activities.tsv',line 5179, character 784 Row 5178, column "SALESFORCE_ACTIVITIES_REPORT" ["INSERT_DATE".19]

Not able to understand the error.
Please help me with it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj0p6.jpg)

Comment: It means the specified line has too few columns, as demarcated by tabs in the line. It hits the end of the line (record) before it finds a value for all columns. Please update your question to include the file format and copy into statements you're using. A sample of that file with the line in question would be helpful too (after being scrubbed of anything sensitive).

Comment: Sorry can't share the file. But file format is .tsv

Comment: Any idea how to rectify it.

Comment: I am actually converting google sheet to .tsv format, then loading to snowflake table. 5 tables were successfully loaded but got error in this one.

Comment: Are you using a file format or just specifying TSV? If you're just specifying TSV, then I would check that line in your file in a text editor that shows unprintable characters. See if there's something that is causing the line to be different, such as tabs inside a column, escape characters, etc. From that you'll need to define a file format to account for them.

Comment: Yes, I download in .tsv format then upload the file into snowflake.

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, please type the error so other people can find it. Also give us some sample data from your .tsv to be able to help further

Comment: See this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69817883/unable-to-load-csv-file-into-snowflake-with-the-copy-into-command
Notice in that case the whole column is missing. Just because Snowflake finds the error in row 5178 doesn't mean the preceding rows are complete.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. I got the error in line 5179. One of the columns was having '/' in the end. After removing that I was able to load the table.